# FineUploader Progressbar questions

Tags: progress-bar, fine-uploader

I'm a bit confused about using the progress event in v3.8 (using the jQuery wrapper)  I understand that only certain browsers that support `ProgressEvent` interface, so I'm testing this in Firefox v20.0.1.

Using some of another's code, I've added this:

```
.on('progress', function (id, filename, uploadedBytes, totalBytes)     
   {                             
        alert('uploadedBytes: ' + uploadedBytes + '\n totalBytes: ' + totalBytes);  
        if (uploadedBytes < totalBytes) {
            progress = '"' + fileName + '" uploading...  ' + Math.round(uploadedBytes / totalBytes*100) +'%';                                                              
                $('#qq-progress-bar').html(progress);
        }
        else {
                $('#qq-progress-bar').html('saving');
        }
   })
```

Please look at the ALERT function within this event, above.  If the input parameters of the method are correct, I shouldn't see the name of the uploaded file displayed in the 'uploadedBytes' parameter.  The totalBytes parameter appears to be correct.  The alert is displayed below:

[image]

I can visibly see the progress bar in certain browsers, such as FireFox v20.0.1 but the bar doesn't progress.  Also, the % value of the amount uploaded doesn't really do much.  I'll see a single value, and then it'll be complete.

To get all this to appear I'm changing the 'qq-progress-bar' as named in the file template.  Am I going about this wrong or making this more complicated than I need to?  I just need to show progress, and a text value isn't required but certainly is nice.  Examples?  Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect, you need to include the `event` parameter when using the jQuery plugin:

```js
.on('progress', function (event, id, filename, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
  alert('uploadedBytes: ' + uploadedBytes + '\n totalBytes: ' + totalBytes);
  if (uploadedBytes < totalBytes) {
    progress = '"' + fileName + '" uploading...  ' + Math.round(uploadedBytes /
      totalBytes * 100) + '%';
    $('#qq-progress-bar').html(progress);
  }
  else {
    $('#qq-progress-bar').html('saving');
  }
})
```

More information is in [the documentation on using jQuery with Fine Uploader.](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html#callbacks-and-events)